# Debug stack trace?

Tags: ios, swift

We received the stack trace below from Flurry. It was captured from a user's device, and we have no way of tracing it. It doesn't list lines from our code base ... how can we troubleshoot the stack trace and isolate the problem?

Full Stack Trace:

```
0   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib          0x34d068f6 <redacted> + 9
1   IMGSGX535GLDriver                   0x2f04050f <redacted> + 122
2   GLEngine                            0x32515a01 <redacted> + 172
3   GLEngine                            0x3251590f _gliPresentViewES + 134
4   OpenGLES                            0x325200cd <redacted> + 64
5   SpriteKit                           0x32990191 -[SKView _renderContent] + 1216
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3af1381f <redacted> + 22
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3af25dd7 <redacted> + 26
8   SpriteKit                           0x3298fca3 -[SKView renderContent] + 82
9   SpriteKit                           0x3298d633 <redacted> + 130
10  SpriteKit                           0x329b00eb -[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 254
11  QuartzCore                          0x32766df3 <redacted> + 98
12  QuartzCore                          0x32766b9d <redacted> + 344
13  IOMobileFramebuffer                 0x354df75d <redacted> + 104
14  IOKit                               0x30f69451 _IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 248
15  CoreFoundation                      0x3023eef9 <redacted> + 136
16  CoreFoundation                      0x30249ab7 <redacted> + 34
17  CoreFoundation                      0x30249a53 <redacted> + 346
18  CoreFoundation                      0x30248227 <redacted> + 1398
19  CoreFoundation                      0x301b2f4f _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
20  CoreFoundation                      0x301b2d33 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
21  GraphicsServices                    0x350b7663 _GSEventRunModal + 138
22  UIKit                               0x32afe16d _UIApplicationMain + 1136
23  <OurClassName>                             0x000af494 __mh_execute_header + 345236
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x3af38ab7 <redacted> + 2
```

Comment: That's _too_ redacted! It's happening while the sprite scene is running. That's all it says.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the base address for each of the modules listed on the left side (your app, plus every system library), because of Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR). Many in-app stack trace reporting tools like PLCrashReporter can store this information in their report.

Next, you need to get the debug symbols for each module. For your app, when you build, it should produce a .dSym file, which contains the information that allows you to get the method and line numbers from the address. You need to make sure to get the exact .dSym that corresponds to the build that produced the crash, because each build is different.

For system libraries, the debug symbols are downloaded by Xcode the first time you connect a device to Xcode using a particular build of the OS. They are stored in `/Users/<yourusername>/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/`. Note that sometimes versions of the OS will have multiple builds (betas, or different build for different devices); you need to get the OS build that the crash happened on, which means your stack trace will also need to store that information. It also needs to be an OS build that your Xcode has seen or else it won't have downloaded the information. For system modules, you will only get the function name and not the line number (which wouldn't be useful anyway since they are not open source).

Then, you can use the tool `atos`, give it an address, a load address (the base address of the module at issue), the architecture (for an app that includes code for multiple architectures), and it will output the symbol information for that address.